# How to check whether there is specific year in phrase?

Tags: python

I have a list of sport game names and need to take out year from it. Say, we have game name 'NHL 2008' in the list, and I need to take 2007 as a game release year  out of the phrase.  Trying to do this:

```
years = list(range(1900,2017))
print(years)
def correct_year(game_name):
    correct_year=0
    for year in years:
        if year in game_name:
            correct_year=year-1
    return correct_year

          
print(correct_year('NHL 2008'))
```

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

How can I check it correctly and get the 'year-1' value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your number to a string:

```
years = list(range(1900,2017))
def correct_year(game_name):
    correct_year=0
    for year in years:
        if str(year) in game_name:
            correct_year=year-1
    return correct_year

          
print(correct_year('NHL 2008'))
```

You can also have it as a one-liner if you use generator comprehension:

```
def correct_year_2(game_name):
    return next(i-1 for i in range(1900,2017) if str(i) in game_name)

print(correct_year_2('NHL 2008'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But what can we do if there is a game like "Need for speed 20000 km arount the US"? It returns 1999 year because '2000' is in '20000'?

Comment: If you need more sophisticated matching you will need to look into regexpressions as demonstrated by Marc

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest to use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) here. It's likely also faster than looping through a list and searching a string a bunch of times. You can look for either a `19` or `20` followed by any two digits:

```
import re

def correct_year(game_name):
    found = re.search(r'((19|20)\d{2})', game_name)
    if found:
        n =  int(found.group(0))
        return n - 1

    
print(correct_year('NHL 1989'))
#1988

print(correct_year('the game in 2010 was amazing'))
#2009

print(correct_year('NHL 15'))
#None

print(correct_year('NHL 1510'))
#None
```

It's not clear if it's possible or what should happen if you somehow have a larger number like `198765`. Currently this will pull `1987` out of it

If you have columnar input, like a bunch of lines in the same format `NHL 1989` you are better off splitting each string to get the date.

Comment: Thanks! Considering your answer and the answer and @user_na, I modified code to solve the problem:

Comment: Thanks! Considering your answer and the answer and @user_na, I tried modified code to solve the problem: instead of found = re.search(r'((19|20)\d{2})', game_name) typed this: `found = re.search(r'((19|20)\d{2}\b)', game_name) print(correct_year('NHL 198765')) #None `but now if there is smth like `print(correct_year('NHL 2008supreme'))` I get "None" now, while in your code it would be "2008". What can be possible solution?